# SQLite in VS 2012

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, sqlite

Ok, spent too much time banging my head with this :)

I need to persist small (under 1000) collection of items between sessions on windows without using full database server. Items are simple objects with dozen or so string properties.
Database/collection/whatever should be stored in a single file that can be created through code in runtime.

Started with SQL server CE then switched to SQLite but now I'm told Entity is a way to go.
I don't mind learning Entity, but seems like too much of an overhead for a simple storage.

What should I do? (if anyone still actually codes windows small databases)

1. Ditch Entity and access SQLite directly through commands.
2. Use Entity with SQLite (Would appreciate link on proper way to create databases at runtime tho)
3. Ditch the whole concept of database (I put this one in because, before, every book had a chapter on databases, now I don't have a single book that mention it. Also not much new stuff on Internet either, so people might moved on to some other concept)

Thanks.

Comment: Does your database need to be used by multiple users?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that :) No it's single user database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like structured textual data - dozen or so string properties.

I would use XML

[XDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Comment: In simple cases where data security is not a MUST, I'd go for XML too; but if you need those records safe, it'll be much better to use file-databases with Password-ing feature; e.g. SQLite, SqlCe or even MS-Access!

Comment: @Achilles There was no mention of sensitive data. User specifically asked for options not using a database. And any data on local hard drive can be hacked - it would slow em down and stop curious editing.

Comment: I'm trying to give the OP some heads-up and suggestions to consider when choosing a Data-Storage; and there are ways to encrypt SQLite databases using AES which makes it really hard to get hacked. http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Data Context with SQL CE, its more than up to the job your describing.

The only problem is that you would only be able to back it up on your local C: Drive. So if that Disk ever died you would lose it all.

There's no need to move over to entity for what you need to do.

If it ever did become something that you would like multiple access to, you would have to re-think this one though.

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm somehow going the same path as you are [VS2012/WPF4] and I found the combination of Dapper+Sqlite works fine for me.
The `System.Data.SQLite`'s design-time support won't be ready before November 2012 and therefore EF5 will be removed from my options.
Check Dapper out:
http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/
This extends `IDbConnection` and you only need to open a connection to whatever database you want.

EDIT: using Dapper, I was unable to automate the data-binding...